# Adding rows to data table and using combo box display member?

Tags: c#

Basically I have a datagrid view with 4 columns and many rows. On top I have a combo box with categories to choose from and depending on that selected item, the datagrid view changes.

The problem is that when adding the rows, I'm adding the same strings over again(ex; Basic Phrases) and the combo box is listing the same strings(so if there is 4 words belonging to Basic Phrases, the combo box is displaying basic phrases 4 times). I will attach my code for better reference.

Is there a better way to do this maybe using an Array?
Thank you.

```
public dgvWordSets()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            table = new DataTable ("Words");
            table.Columns.Add("English", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("French", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Italian", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("WordSets", typeof(string));


            table.Rows.Add("Hello", "Salut", "Salve", "Basic Phrases");
            table.Rows.Add("Good night", "Bonne nuit", "Buonanotte", "Basic Phrases");
            table.Rows.Add("Good evening", "Bonsoir", "Buonasera", "Basic Phrases");
            table.Rows.Add("Excuse me", "Excusez-moi", "Scusa", "Basic Phrases");
            table.Rows.Add("Please", "S'il vous plait", "Per favore", "Basic Phrases");
            table.Rows.Add("Dog", " Le chien", "Il cane", "Animals");
            table.Rows.Add("Cat", "Le chat", "Il gatto", "Animals");
            table.Rows.Add("Jacket", "Un veste", "La giacca", "Clothes");

            comboBox1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "WordSets";
}

  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
                {
                    DataRowView view = comboBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
                    string WordSets = view["WordSets"].ToString();

                    DataRow[] rows = table.Select("WordSets = '" + WordSets + "'");
                    DataTable newTable = table.Clone();
                    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                        newTable.ImportRow(row);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = newTable.DefaultView;
                }
```

Comment: Well your DisplayMember is "WordSets" so it's going to show Basic Phrases in each ComboBox item. You want a different DisplayMember such as "English" which will show all the English words.

Comment: I just want to show the categories so for example "Basic Phrases" "Animals" "Clothes...in the combo box...and there will be 52 for each displayed in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combox should not have as DataSource the whole table but only the Distinct values of the table

```
List<string>wordsets = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("WordSets")).Distinct().ToList();
comboBox1.DataSource = wordsets;
dataGridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Now when you select something from the combo you don't need to build a separate datatable but you can simply set the DefaultView.RowFilter for the table variable

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        string word = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "WordSets = '" + word + "'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
    }
}
```